# question about CPP class that when to using smart pointer prefer raw object?

Tags: c++

such as the below code, EmbedderEngine has some members, what question I asked is when using a raw object as a member and when using a smart pointer as a member of a class. why not always use a smart pointer? can you help me?

```
 class EmbedderEngine{
 .....
 private:
  const std::unique_ptr<EmbedderThreadHost> thread_host_;
  TaskRunners task_runners_;
  RunConfiguration run_configuration_;
  std::unique_ptr<ShellArgs> shell_args_;
  std::unique_ptr<Shell> shell_;
  std::unique_ptr<EmbedderExternalTextureResolver> external_texture_resolver_;
  FML_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(EmbedderEngine);
};
```

Comment: Which member is a pointer and which member is an object completely depends on design choices. If there is a design doc, please read it.  Else talk to the person who has written the code.

Comment: You should only use a smart-pointer when necessary (e.g. when you know you will need to transfer ownership of the sub-object to someone else, or when the sub-object's lifetime might last longer than the object that owns it).  By default use a raw member-variable object since that is simpler and more efficient in most cases.

Comment: If you are asking about including member variables directly or allocating them on the heap and storing an owning `unique_ptr`: If the size is variable, you cannot store the object directly. But it is possible that the member itself uses heap storage, e.g. you can put a `std::vector` directly into an object as member variable and can do similarly with your 'subobjects'. Storing directly has caching advantages and you need less indirection and have no allocation overhead. The code is also more clean and you risk less of a resource leak. So the standard approach should be storing directly.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it's a better way to solve it. Thanks @JeremyFriesner